# Driver required for USB-3 hub support on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb-3, usb-hub

I just purchased a Koutech HU-430 4-port USB SuperSpeed hub.

When plugged into a USB-3 port using the included USB3 A/B cable, Windows detects it as a "Renesas Electronics USB 2.0 hub".

[image]

Does this mean the device is faulty, or I need to install another driver?

The VID is 0x2109, PID is 0x3431 as shown:

[image]

Device descriptors (from MS USBView, which probably isn't aware of USB3 flags):

```
External Hub: USB#VID_2109&PID_3431#6&2d180087&0&3#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}
Hub Power:               Self Power
Number of Ports:         4
Power switching:         Individual
Compound device:         No
Over-current Protection: Individual

Extended Hub Capability Flags:  0x000003
    High speed Capable:  Yes
    High speed:  Yes
    Mulit-transaction Capable:  No
    Mulit-transaction ON:  No
    Root hub:  No
    Armed for wake on connect:  No
    Reserved (26 bits):  000000

Device Descriptor:
bcdUSB:             0x0200
bDeviceClass:         0x09
bDeviceSubClass:      0x00
bDeviceProtocol:      0x01
bMaxPacketSize0:      0x40 (64)
idVendor:           0x2109
idProduct:          0x3431
bcdDevice:          0x0276
iManufacturer:        0x00
iProduct:             0x01
iSerialNumber:        0x00
bNumConfigurations:   0x01

ConnectionStatus: DeviceConnected
Current Config Value: 0x01
Device Bus Speed:     High
Device Address:       0x01
Open Pipes:              1

Endpoint Descriptor:
bEndpointAddress:     0x81  IN
Transfer Type:   Interrupt
wMaxPacketSize:     0x0001 (1)
bInterval:            0x0C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest Renesas driver (2.1.25.0) fixed the issue.

[image]

My motherboard manufacturer hasn't bothered to place the new driver on their website, but Intel has it [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/confirm.aspx?httpDown=http://downloadmirror.intel.com/19880/eng/USB3.0_allOS_2.1.25.0_PV.exe&lang=eng&Dwnldid=19880&DownloadType=%0aDrivers%0a&OSFullname=%0a&ProductID=3336)

As seen, the hub shows up as two devices (with the correct driver), here are the descriptors for the second device (Unfortunately I didn't notice whether this was listed before the driver upgrade):

```
External Hub: USB#VID_2109&PID_0810#6&2d180087&0&1#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}
Hub Power:               Self Power
Number of Ports:         4
Power switching:         Individual
Compound device:         No
Over-current Protection: Individual

Extended Hub Capability Flags:  0x000001
    High speed Capable:  Yes
    High speed:  No
    Mulit-transaction Capable:  No
    Mulit-transaction ON:  No
    Root hub:  No
    Armed for wake on connect:  No
    Reserved (26 bits):  000000

Device Descriptor:
bcdUSB:             0x0300
bDeviceClass:         0x09
bDeviceSubClass:      0x00
bDeviceProtocol:      0x03
bMaxPacketSize0:      0x09 (9)
idVendor:           0x2109
idProduct:          0x0810
bcdDevice:          0x0376
iManufacturer:        0x01
iProduct:             0x02
iSerialNumber:        0x00
bNumConfigurations:   0x01

ConnectionStatus: DeviceConnected
Current Config Value: 0x01
Device Bus Speed:     Unknown
Device Address:       0x02
Open Pipes:              1

Endpoint Descriptor:
bEndpointAddress:     0x81  IN
Transfer Type:   Interrupt
wMaxPacketSize:     0x0002 (2)
bInterval:            0x10
```

Comment: Nice detective work on the driver, how did you ever find it? Which Motherboard do you have?

Comment: @Moab: I have a Gigabyte GA-P55A-UD4P.  I found the driver based on a clue left in a Newegg review saying to get it from Intel, took a little hunting around the Intel download site.